# when chrome extension gets updated does the data stored in local storage gets deleted?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have searched through google spec about chrome storage, but was not able to get a definite answer to my question.

I am currently writing my first chrome extension, in which I store the data into a local storage.

The thing that is bothering me is that when I release the next version of the extension, does the local storage get deleted when the extension in updated at the user end ?

Because during development, what I observed, is that whenever I delete the extension and re-install it via **"Load Unpacked Extension"**, the data already stored is deleted, apparently.

So does this behavior holds true when updating the extension as well ?

Comment: When the extension is deleted, its stored data is also deleted. Updating is not the same thing as deleting.

Comment: happens to me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have it in 'Chrome Web Store' and you update the extension is not removed. However if you use 'Load Extension Unpacked' or 'Reload Extension' is removed

Comment: So you mean that the data stored in the local storage gets deleted when updated ? Also, I believe Sync works only if the person is signed in into chrome, But in my case, there is no such requirement. The Person might or might not be signed in.

Comment: @SubodhShetty If you have it in 'Chrome Web Store' and you update the extension is not removed. However if you use 'Load Extension Unpacked' or 'Reload Extension' is removed

Comment: this answer is incorrect. should not be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @ZigMandel Using "Load Extension Unpacked", the data is removed, however, if the answer is not correct there any way to remove the answer if it is marked?

Comment: you marked it correct and you can unmark it. there is some good explanation in comments but really it should be in the answer and it also contradicts the answer.

Comment: @ZigMandel, I can't unmark, the button shows a arrow green disabled. That should do question's creator.

Comment: ahhh sorry! you are the answerer. i recommend you edit your answer and add the info you put in comments. then people might undo their -1

Comment: @ZigMandel I just did, my mistake was not to edit my own answer. Although I doubt that they withdraw the down vote, because I'm not sure if they will again see the question. Ty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79850/discussion-between-wzvang-and-zig-mandel).

Comment: but why do you still recommend sync? its really unrelated to the q and requires more explanations

Comment: Load unpacked will delete the storage only if you get a different Extension ID once you install the new version over the previous one. However you can prevent that by adding a static key.